# Best Way to Bulk Scan Center Stapled Booklets

Tags: archiving, scanner, documents, scanning

I wanted to scan some A4-Sized Textbooks that had the centre stapled binding. There are around 60 (15-25 sheets each) of them that I wanted to scan as soon as possible. Is there any way I can scan with decent quality and minimize any sort of destruction to the books?

I use Adobe Acrobat for the PDF Management, Scanning Interface etc and use my printer's scanner that does have ADF but I have to manually flip it over as it does not have duplex scanning.

Answer (score 0):

There is a product line from [CZUR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JCNQ8DK) that performs open book scanning. It's effectively a camera mounted on a gooseneck. The software "un-distorts" the image captured by the camera.

[image: czur scanner]

[image: czur scanner info]
Images from Amazon linked site.

Comment: Not A Viable Option for me. In my country it costs more than a grand...